# Implementing the Observer Pattern to get notified about every new Account

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I am developing an application where I would like to use the observer pattern in the following way:
I have 2 classes:

```
public abstract class Storage<V>{
    private Set<V> values;
    private String filename;

    protected Storage(String filename) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        values = new HashSet<>();
        this.filename = filename;
        load();
    }

    ...

    public boolean add(V v) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (values.contains(v))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("L'elemento è già presente");
        return values.add(v);
    }

    ...
}
```

`Repository` which is a class for saving a collection of Objects. below is a subclass that implements the singleton pattern (the others are practically the same, only the specified generic type changes)

```
public class AccountStorage extends Storage<Account>{
    
    private static AccountStorage instance = null;

    private AccountStorage(String filename) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        super(filename);
    }
    
    public static synchronized AccountStorage getInstance() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        if (instance == null) {
            String savefile = "accounts.ob";
            instance = new AccountStorage(savefile);
        }

        return instance;
    }
```

after which I have a controller class (Controller for Spring MVC) which through a post request receives an Account in JSON format, deserializes it and adds it to the collection (Tremite the `AccountStorage` class) like this:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "new/user", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> newAccount(@RequestBody Account a) {

        synchronized (accounts) {
            try {
                accounts.add(a);
                // accounts.save()
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }   

        }
    }
```

where accounts is: `AccountStorage accounts = AccountStorage.getInstance();`

I would like to make sure that, after each addition (or other methods that modify the collection) it is saved to file without calling the function affixed each time after the modification.

My idea is to use the Observer pattern. But I don't know which class must be an *Observer* and which *Observable* (assuming this approach is the correct solution).

Comment: Consider following Josh Bloch's advice in "Effective Java" by implementing your Singleton using an enum. See https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3 and https://riptutorial.com/java/example/5741/implement-singleton-pattern-with-a-single-element-enum

Comment: Also, consider making your Storage class inherently thread-safe instead of requiring external synchronization. Use `values = ConcurrentHashMap<V, Boolean>.newKeySet();` and make your `add` method atomic by directly calling `Set.add` first, and if that returns false, then throw your exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common practice for implementing the [*Observer pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is to define an `Observer` interface (*Listener*) which will declare a general contact and each *observer-implementation* should provide an action which would be triggered whenever an *event* occurs.

A **subject** maintains a collection of *observers* (listeners), and exposes methods which allow to *add* and *remove* (*subscribe/unsubscribe*) an *observer*. Event-related behavior resides in the *subject*, and when a new event happens, every subscribed observer (i.e. each observer that is currently present in the collection) will be notified.

[image]

An *event* to which we are going to listen to is a case when a new `Account` gets added into an `AccountStorage`. And `AccountStorage` would be a *subject*. That implies that `AccountStorage` should hold a reference to a collection of *observers*, provide a functionality to *subscribe/unsubscribe* and override method `add()` of the `Storage` class in order to trigger all the *observers* when a new *account* will be added.

Why can't we add a collection of *observers* and all related functionality into the `Storage` class so that every implementation will inherit it? It's a valid question, the answer is that in such a scenario we can't be specific in regard to the nature of the *event* because we even don't know its type - method `add(V)` expects a mysterious `V`. Hence, the *observer* interface and its method would be faceless. It was the downside of the standard interfaces `Observer` and `Observable` that are deprecated since JDK version 9. Their names as well as the method-name `update()` tell nothing about an event that would be observed. It's only slightly better than define an interface `MyInterface` with a method `myMethod()` - no clue where you can use it and what actions should follow when `myMethod()` is fired.

It's a good practice when names of *observers* are descriptive, so that it's clear without looking at the code what they are meant to do. And it's not only related to the Observer pattern, it is a general practice which is called a [*self-documenting code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code).

Let's start by defining an *observer* interface, I'll call it *listener* just because `AccountAddedListener` sounds a bit smoothly, and it's quite common to use the terms *listener* and *observer* interchangeably.

```
public interface AccountAddedListener {
    void onAccountAdded(Account account);
}
```

Now let's proceed with an implementation of the *observer*, let's say we need a notification manager:

```
public class NotificationManager implements AccountAddedListener {
    
    @Override
    public void onAccountAdded(Account account) {
        // send a notification message
    }
}
```

Now it's time to turn the `AccountStorage` into a *subject*. It should maintain a reference collection of *observers*, `Set` is a good choice because it'll not allow to add the same *observer* twice (which would be pointless) and is able to *add* and *remove* elements in a constant time.

Whenever a new account gets added, *subject* iterates over the collection of *observers* and invokes `onAccountAdded()` method on each of them.

We need to define a method to *add* a new *observer*, and it's also good practice to add another one to be able to *unregister* the observer when it's no longer needed.

```
public class AccountStorage extends Storage<Account> {

    private Set<AccountAddedListener> listeners = new HashSet<>(); // collection of observers
    
    @Override
    public boolean add(Account account) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.onAccountAdded(account)); // notifying observers
        
        return super.add(account);
    }
    
    public boolean registerAccountAddedListener(AccountAddedListener listener) {
        return listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public boolean unregisterAccountAddedListener(AccountAddedListener listener) {
        return listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    // all other functionality of the AccountStorage 
}
```